# Maximize code tab in eclipse shortcut

Tags: eclipse, editor

Is there any shortcut for maximizing the tab you are working on in Eclipse? Assume I am working on part of a code and I want to maximize the tab not using the double click on it with the mouse, does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> will maximize/restore the editor area.

If you can't remember all shortcuts, then just learn <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. That will show a list of available shortcuts.

[Some more shortcuts](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html) can be found on external sites.

Comment: Actually it's faster to Google than look at Ctrl-Shift-L :)
Thanks!

Comment: btw: on macOS the default shortcut to bring up the list of available shortcuts - at least for Eclipse Neon (4.6.1) - is cmd + shift + L

Comment: If you are on windows and using Mobaxterm, Ctrl+M will not maximize the Eclipse's editor pane, instead it will hide/show the Mobaxterm. Solution: In Mobaxterm => Settings => Keyboard Short Cut => Change CTRL+M to something else. Restart the Mobaxterm.