# Eclipse: Hotkey to toggle tab maximize/minimize

Tags: eclipse

Often when I'm working in Eclipse, I'll be in a perspective (say debug) and doing stuff there, then I want to maximize a file I'm looking at.  I double-click it, and work on it, then double-click again to minimize back to the debug perspective.

Is there a hot-key to do this from the keyboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximize code tab in eclipse shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411750/maximize-code-tab-in-eclipse-shortcut)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  will maximize/restore the editor area.

If you can't remember all shortcuts, then just learn <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. That will show a list of available shortcuts.

Also: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html#link_11

Link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html

Link: [Maximize code tab in eclipse shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411750/maximize-code-tab-in-eclipse-shortcut)

Comment: nice, what a relief.  Best hotkey since ctrl-shift-r.

Comment: ya dude it's a goldmine :)