# comment lines with syntax error

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for WebDevelopers in Version Luna (4.4.2).

Is there any way to comment lines with syntax error via shortcut automatically? I mean not just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on every line (with syntax errors) manually.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I just re-created a project through a clean up (yes, small project so far). I just changed the package name and need to change all classes as well. It just came into my mind. Also I had methods, which are no longer there. I just want to comment all erros in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one short cut to do what you require, but you could use a combination.

**Windows Short Cuts**

- Go to the next error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd>
- Go to the previous error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**,**</kbd>

**Then**

- Comment that error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>

**Extra**

If you really wanted you could download a add-on and create a macro to automate the two short cuts into one.

[Stackoverflow - Is there a Macro Recorder for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would chime in with some helpful shortcuts from [my other answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980588/eclipse-hotkey-to-toggle-tab-maximize-minimize/25980723#25980723)

If you can't remember all shortcuts, then just learn <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. That will show a list of available shortcuts.

Also: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html#link_11

Link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html

Link: [Maximize code tab in eclipse shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411750/maximize-code-tab-in-eclipse-shortcut)